# Wierd output using paste with serial option

Tags: text-processing, newlines, paste

I have a `testA.txt` with contents as shown below

```
[jiewmeng@JM textFiles]$ cat testA.txt 
The quick
brown fox
jumped over
the lazy 
dog.
```

paste normally works

```
[jiewmeng@JM textFiles]$ paste testA.txt 
The quick
brown fox
jumped over
the lazy 
dog.
```

But what happened when I used serial?

```
[jiewmeng@JM textFiles]$ paste -s testA.txt 
The quicdog.lazy er

[jiewmeng@JM textFiles]$ paste -s -d- testA.txt 
-dog.lazy er
```

I was expecting output similar to

```
[jiewmeng@JM tmp]$ echo -en "The quick\nbrown fox\njumped over\nthe lazy\ndog" | paste -s -
The quick   brown fox   jumped over the lazy    dog
```

Opening the file in a test editor seems to work fine, just like `cat`, or `paste` did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file contains CR+LF [line ending](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).  (You can say `cat -vet inputfile` to figure that.  Carriage returns would show up as `^M` in the output.)

The following demonstrates the effect of line endings on the output:

```
$ cat test.txt
The quick
brown fox
jumped over
the lazy
dog.
$ paste -s test.txt
The quick       brown fox       jumped over     the lazy        dog.
$ unix2dos test.txt
$ paste -s test.txt
        dog.lazy er
```